# RadListView not orientating horizontally with NativeScript Angular 2

Tags: angular, nativescript, horizontal-scrolling, radlistview

I know I am missing something small. RadListView is not orientating horizontally. I have tried many things but it's not switching. Testing on Android. Please give me some advice. Thanks

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout height="400">
        <Label text="Sale Produce" class="h3 title-regular"
            textWrap="true" height="40">
        </Label>
        <lv:RadListView id="salelistView" [items]="saleProducts"
            height="100" orientation="Horizontal">
            <lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
                <lv:ListViewLinearLayout
                    tkListViewLayout scrollDirection="horizontal"
                    itemHeight="100" itemWidth="150" />
            </lv:RadListView.listViewLayout>
            <ng-template let-item="item">
                <StackLayout orientation="Horizontal" width="180">
                    <GridLayout rows="*,*" columns="1*,1*"
                        class="list-item-regular">
                        <Image row="0" col="0" rowSpan="2"
                            src="{{'https...net'+item.image}}"
                            stretch="aspectFill"></Image>
                        <Label row="0" col="1" text="{{ item.name }}"
                            class="h3 date-regular" textWrap="true"
                            height="40">  
                        </Label>
                        <Label row="1" col="1"
                            text="{{'R'+item.price+'.00'}}"
                            class="h4 date-regular" textWrap="true"
                            height="30">
                        </Label>
                    </GridLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </lv:RadListView>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: i have faced this problem many times. Just replace all your stacklayout by gridlayout. and always avoid putting grid inside stack. let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks bud. Trying that now. Do you know why this is the rule of thumb?

Comment: I seriously don't know. I just frustrated with stacklayout as it always complains.

Comment: Changed all StackLayout to GridLayout and still the RadListView is not listing horizontally or scrolling horizintally.

Comment: Is it iOS / Android? Are you able to reproduce the issue with Playground?

Comment: @Manoj  i am currently testing on android. The sample is on playground where i am seeing the issue.

Comment: Can you you attach the link to Playground sample?